# Sockets showing old data

Tags: c#

for some reason my sockets are showing data that had been received in another part of the code.
For example, when I login it works fine but then I send a chat message from the server and it shows the username send from the login.

Here is the network classes from the server:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Banshee_Server
    {
        class Network
        {
            public Socket listener;
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
            public const int BufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

            public static Dictionary<Socket, Player> dictionary = new Dictionary<Socket, Player>();

            public Player getPlayer(Socket socket)
            {
                if (socket != null)
                {
                    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(socket))
                    {
                        return dictionary[socket];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public bool playerIsLoggedIn(String player)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Socket sock in dictionary.Keys)
                    {
                        if (getPlayer(sock).Name.ToLower() == player.ToLower())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                catch {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public static int getFreePlayerIndex
            {
                get { return Network.dictionary.Count(); }
            }

            netHandler handlers = new netHandler();

            public Network(Socket socket, int port)
            {
                this.listener = socket;
                localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
            }

            public void bindListener()
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            }
            public void startListening()
            {

                try
                {

                    listener.Listen(100);
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar){
                Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
                startListening();
                handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), handler);
                Common common = new Common();
                common.appendLog("New Connection received from " + handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            }

            public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar){
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                try
                {
                    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        byte[] byteData = new byte[bytesRead];
                        byteData = buffer;
                        byte[] readData = new byte[byteData.Length - 1];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, 1, readData, 0, readData.Length);
                        sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readData));
                        String data = sb.ToString();



                        handlers.handleData(handlers.getHandlerType(byteData[0]), data, handler);

                        handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), handler);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), handler);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }

            private static void sendFileCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                client.EndSendFile(ar);
            }

            public void Send(Socket sock, String data, byte dataType)
            {
                byte[] byteType = new byte[1];
                byteType[0] = dataType;

                int bufferSize = byteType.Length + Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data).Length;
                var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[bufferSize], 0, bufferSize, true, true);
                ms.Write(byteType, 0, byteType.Length);
                ms.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data).Length);

                byte[] byteData = ms.GetBuffer();

                sock.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), sock);
            }

            public void SendtoAll(String data, byte dataType)
            {

                try
                {
                    foreach (Socket sock in dictionary.Keys)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Send(sock, data, dataType);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            handlers.logoutPlayer(sock, this);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }


            private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {

                    Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                    int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And here is the network class from the Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Ghoul_Engine
{
    class network
    {

        public Socket sock;
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public Byte[] buffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
        public IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint;



        public network()
        {


        }

        public void beginConnect(Socket socket)
        {
            sock = socket;
            try
            {
                sock.BeginConnect(RemoteEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(onConnect), sock);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to remote server. Perhaps it's down.");
            }
        }

        public void onConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                sock.EndConnect(ar);
                sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), sock);
            } catch{
                MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to server, it could be down!");
            }
        }

        public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                int bytesRead = sock.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] byteData = new byte[bytesRead];
                byteData = buffer;
                byte[] readData = new byte[byteData.Length - 1];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, 1, readData, 0, readData.Length);
                sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readData));
                String data = sb.ToString();



                Program.netHandlers.handleData(Program.netHandlers.getHandlerType(byteData[0]), data, sock);
                if(sock.Connected){
                    sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), sock);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(sock.Connected){
                    sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), sock);
                }

            }
            }
            catch { }

        }



        public void Send(String data, byte dataType)
        {
            byte[] byteType = new byte[1];
            byteType[0] = dataType;

            int bufferSize = byteType.Length + Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data).Length;
            var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[bufferSize], 0, bufferSize, true, true);
            ms.Write(byteType, 0, byteType.Length);
            ms.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data).Length);

            byte[] byteData = ms.GetBuffer(); 

            sock.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), sock);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void closeSocket()
        {
            try
            {
                if (sock.Connected)
                {
                    sock.Close();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public Socket getSocket()
        {
            return sock;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Too much code, please reduce that to a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Well, too much code. Have you tried to debug and follow the data using F11?

Answer (score 2):

In your server, you have a `buffer` member of your `Network` class, but you have multiple execution paths happening concurrently for each client. If you try to use this same buffer for all clients, you're going to have these conflicts.

I'd recommend that you don't use a shared buffer, but use a separate buffer for each message.

Answer (score 0):

Your big chunk of code here:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] byteData = new byte[bytesRead];
        byteData = buffer;
        byte[] readData = new byte[byteData.Length - 1];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, 1, readData, 0, readData.Length);
        sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readData));
        String data = sb.ToString();
```

Can simply be replaced with:

```
        String data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

As to your problem, I don't see anything obvious in the code you posted.  The problem might be in your **handleData()** method.

Comment: I have a theory that I'm about to test I think it has to do with left over bytes in buffer[] not being set back to null.

Comment: That shouldn't matter since `bytesRead` will tell you how much of `buffer` has valid data in it.  Unless you were talking about a different buffer?